# CSS - Can't get the z-index to apply correctly in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, z-index

I've written a jQuery script to replace `<select />` elements with some DIV's and UL's allowing my to simulate the original SELECT but also allow me to style it. So far, aside from a few minor bugs, it works rather nicely.

However, in Internet Explorer, the 'options' div is getting rendered underneath the elements below the div.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="styledSelect-parent" style="display: inline-block; width: 59px;">
   <div class="styledSelect-newSelect" style="position: relative;">
      <input class="styledSelect-newSelect-selector" style="width: 59px;" readonly="readonly" name="hello" value="Test1" type="text">
      <div class="styledSelect-newSelect-options" style="display: none; z-index: 20; width: 59px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 18px;">
         <ul>
            <li>Test1</li>
            <li>Test2</li>
            <li>Test3</li>
            <li class="styledSelect-active">Test4</li>
            <li>Test1</li>
            <li>Test2</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<br /><br />

<div class="styledSelect-parent" style="display: inline-block; width: 59px;">
   <div class="styledSelect-newSelect" style="position: relative;">
      <input class="styledSelect-newSelect-selector" style="width: 59px;" readonly="readonly" name="hello" value="Test1" type="text">
      <div class="styledSelect-newSelect-options" style="display: none; z-index: 20; width: 59px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 18px;">
         <ul>
            <li class="styledSelect-active">Test1</li>
            <li>Test2</li>
            <li>Test3</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If I open the first select, the LI list sits underneath the second select box rather than above it. I can't get the z-indexes to work properly.

What am I missing? :/

**EDIT:** I should point out the HTML is generated dynamically from jQuery. The full code can be found [here](http://slexy.org/raw/s20SG0C5og).

Comment: Do you have a live example of this?

Comment: No but I've uploaded the code to Slexy. So save it locally and it should be good to go. http://slexy.org/raw/s20SG0C5og

Comment: Working example from the source you provided here: http://jsfiddle.net/hF75W/ What exactly is the problem? This displays exactly as running locally on FF.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/8BaI9.jpg <-- This is what I'm seeing in Internet Explorer. The first select box is opened and rendering below the second. In Firefox, it works perfectly. The first select box's DIV (of options) overlaps the second select box.

Answer (score 1):

"In Internet Explorer positioned elements generate a new stacking context, starting with a z-index value of 0. Therefore z-index  doesn't work correctly". http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html

Comment: The hack solution to this is to use an iframe shim underneath the element/block you're needing to 'float'. Mootools (and I believe jQuery) have a plugin to automate this.